Debian and TCL TV
I'm running Debian 12 with Cinnamon on a TCL 98S550G TV (HDMI-0, connected to HDMI 1 on the TV). The desktop is always on, with screensaver after 5 mins and screen off after 45 mins.
With my old TV, I could just hit the spacebar, power on the TV, and start using the computer. With the new TV, I have to power on the TV first, wait for the "no signal" message, then hit the spacebar. If I hit the spacebar first, the TV shows no signal on HDMI-1.
To fix this, I switch to a console (CTRL+ALT+F1-6) and then back to the desktop (CTRL+ALT+F7). This is a hassle, especially for family members.
I'm looking for a workaround to make the computer send signals via HDMI-0 automatically. I've considered using a background script triggered by "Detected that screensaver has left the bus" in .xsession-errors, but I'm unsure what commands to use to either simulate the switch to/from the console or reset the display to reconnect with the TV.
Any suggestions for a proper fix (like xorg.conf or /etc/default/grub.d) or other ideas are welcome!
